# Partitions not returning any results in Amazon Athena

Tags: mysql, csv, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have created a table in amazon athena. I have my data as CSV file(one large file having data from 2010-2015).It is not partitioned in s3. I am trying to create partitions in athena but partitions are not pulling any results.

step 1: creating table in athena

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DATABASE.table1 (
NULL string,
OrderID string,
CustomerID string,
EmailAddress string
)
PARTITIONED BY (OrderDate STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
 'serialization.format' = ',',
  'quoteChar' = '"',
  'field.delim' = ','
) LOCATION 's3://XYZ/Orders/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

After this STEP 2: Loading partitions manually (my orderdate format is mm/dd/yy hrs min)

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD PARTITION (orderdate='01/01/2010 00:00') location 's3://xyz/Orders/'
```

Its says partition has been created successfully but when i query against this i dont get any results.So am I creating partitions in a wrong way? why it is not returning results?Any help is appreciated.

After trying out the comments below i am still not able to retrieve any results when i query data using order date.I uploaded my files again to athena(two separate files for two years) where the path of files looks like this

```
s3://xyz/Orders/year/orders+2010.csv
 s3://xyz/Orders/year/orders+2014.csv
```

After doing this I am still not able to the partitions and query data using date range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partitions are sub-directories. When correctly defined Athena can skip over sub-directories that do not contain relevant data.

For example, if a table is partitioned by date (YYYY-MM-DD), there would be a directory called `date=2017-11-08` that contains only data for that day.

Given that all your data is contained in a single CSV, you *cannot* use partitions. If you were to divide the file into individual daily files within an appropriate directory structure, Athena would run faster for you and would be cheaper to operate.

Athena cannot generate the partitions for you -- you must provide Athena with data that is already partitioned. The `ADD PARTITION` and `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` commands merely scan in and use the existing partitions.

See AWS Big Data blog: [Analyzing Data in S3 using Amazon Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyzing-data-in-s3-using-amazon-athena/)

Comment: ..Thanku For resolving the issue and it makes complete sense now why i was not able to get any results. I have one more doubt my date format is mm-dd-yyyy hrs-min but athena takes the other date format. Will data make any difference if i reload everything again to s3 with separate date ranges for each year?

Comment: The table definition in your question appears to be treating the Date field as a String, so it doesn't matter what format you use, as long as your queries match the format in which it is stored. However, if you are manipulating dates (eg selecting data for the last 5 days), it would be better to define it as an actual date field.

Comment: ...with opencsvserde if i use any other data type than string it gives me parsing error. So I don't know whats the solution to that.

Answer (score 0):

One interesting point, folders in S3 are [not actually folders](https://serverfault.com/questions/435827/what-is-the-difference-between-buckets-and-folders-in-amazon-s3), I tend to think of them as tags.  To John's point, you need to slice and dice your data and then tag it as such:

```
s3://mybucket/mydata/date_partition=2017-01-01/customer_partition=12345/somdedata.csv
```

Certain applications such as the web UI and S3 browser present S3 "folders" as directories, but when you start making API calls you'll find they don't behave as such.

One of the nice things about this structure is that Athena will treat all files with a certain "tag" (such as `date_partition=2017-01-01/customer_partition=12345/`) as being in the same partition.  So, to Athena, these are equivalent:

```
s3://mystuff/data/date_partition=2017-01-01/customer_partition=12345/somehugefile.csv
s3://mystuff/data/date_partition=2017-01-01/customer_partition=12345/asmallerfile.csv
s3://mystuff/data/date_partition=2017-01-01/customer_partition=12345/anothersmallerfile.csv
```

Sometimes, splitting data like this can be really useful.

Comment: @John Rotenstein  I am still not able to retrieve any information back. Cna you please help me out